# How to retain the Session vars when deploying in Clouds and Cluster servers?

Tags: cluster, cloud

How do you ensure your user retains the same session information when your application is deployed to a cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your session data in a database or something like memcached or redis.